# How to centre an element?

Tags: css, wordpress

On some pages the element is located to the left of the screen. For example:

https://athleteperks.co.uk/choose-plan/

What code do I use or what do I edit to make it central?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the `container` class to the parent of the `.row`:

```
<div class="spb_wrapper spb-asset-content spb_pricing_table_wrapper container">
```

And you will get:

[image: preview]

Comment: I can't seem to find the code you have shown above.